# UIButton not working in Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have created XIB for custom `UITableViewCell`. And inflated this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I used cell accessoryType and `UIButton` above accessoryType view. So the button click event is not working. If I remove the accessoryType, it is working fine.

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

I used for button focus,

```
[cell bringSubviewToFront:cell.aButton];
```

But this also not working.

What will I do to use accessoryType and `UIButton` in Custom `UITableViewCell`?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting the Z position of the button? I know that fixed an issue I had of a progress hud showing up behind the separators on a table view (bringing subview to front did not help, so maybe the Z position would work here, too). `[cell.aButton.layer setZPosition:10000];`

Comment: Can you show the code that adds the button to the tableview cell?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the button into the contentView of the cell. You should be able to do this in interface builder or in code by

```
[cell.contentView addSubview: aButton];
```

The `contentView` of a `tableViewCell` is where objects like UIButtons and UIImageViews are placed.

Comment: While the subviews should be added to the `contentView`, that does not necessarily mean that they are accessed via `cell.contentView`. A public `property` of the cell (such as a `UIButton *aButton`) would be accessed via `cell.aButton` even if it has been placed in the cell's `contentView`.